# Create NPM package that packages a data blob

Tags: javascript, node.js, blob, parceljs

### Objective

To create an npm package, that

- exports a single constant, `data` that is an array of JS objects e.g.

```
const export data = [{a:1, b:2}, {a:3, b:4}];
```

- works in the browser *and* Node (but if only one is possible, prefer browser);
- is minimal size.

### What I tried

I have a working Node implementation, which builds with Parcel. It packages a data file (.csv) and an index.js which reads (using d3) and parses (using fs) the csv at runtime to a constant variable `data`. This works fine in Node.

### The problem

The bundled version fails, because of the reliance on `fs`, which is Node-only. So I would like to know:

1. whether there is a suitable alternative to `fs` which is browser-friendly (I couldn't figure this out);
2. whether there is a better, surely more straightforward way of packaging a blob of consistent data like this. It feels awfully like I am reinventing many wheels, with unnecessary pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting the CSV in a `.csv` file, you can export a string from another JS file, e.g. `data.js`:

```js
export default `[paste csv here]`
```

Then simply import it and use that file:

```js
import csv from "./data"
```

This is nice because after bundling the CSV is in the same file, but it doesn't clutter your code.

Alternatively, I found an npm package that's a parcel plugin that just might do it for you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel-transformer-csv

Answer (score 2):

Parcel or other bundlers are complete overkill for this. All you need is a small script that takes the following steps:

- Read the CSV using some csv parser into the structure you need.
- Write a file in the current directory `index.js` using something like:

```js
fs.writeFileSync('./index.js', `export const data = ${JSON.stringify(myData)};`):
```

And then the important part is that you do this during *build time* before you you publish the package. The published package only needs the generated file, not the csv or build scripts or any dependencies.

Comment: Wouldn't the need to be non-reliant on `fs` (specified in the OP) preclude this?

Comment: @RobertHarvey no because this only happens during *build time*, not runtime. This means that the code only runs when creating the npm .tgz , but when anyone uses the package there's no `fs` or `csv`.

Comment: I have a feeling that import a CSV file is not the sole reason the OP uses Parcel?

Comment: @code possible! but it sounded like this was the only export in this package, and even so this is still probably the cleanest solution.